# Fitting a nonlinear regression $Y=1 - a^{-bx}$

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression, exponential-distribution, trend, exponential-smoothing

I have the following dataset:

[image]

where

```
X:Y
1:0.81
2:0.86
4:0.9
6:0.93
8:0.96
10:0.98
12:0.99
14:0.99
16:1
18:1
20:1
..:1
```

Since the limit of the regression function for large X should be 1, I assumed a proper regression should be in a form of $Y = 1 - a^{-bx}$. However, I'm having difficulty to obtain it. Any idea would be appreciated.

NOTE: The function, indeed, approaches the asymptote `Y=1` but the variability is insignificant for `X>=16` in my experiments. That's why I assumed 1 after some larger `X`'s.

Comment: Can you say a little more about what you tried? E.g. did you try fitting the parameters (how?) and what happened.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify more; either a distributional model for Y|X=x (or at the least how the spread would be expected to change - e.g. how it will change with x, or how it will relate to E(Y|x=x)) OR you need to specify a loss function.

For example

- if you expect the spread to be constant as the function increases and then approaches the asymptote, you might consider using nonlinear least squares. However this seems unlikely from your data (once it reaches 1 there's literally no variability in the data).
- if the observations cannot exceed or exactly reach 1 and you expect Y to be less spread as the curve approaches the asymptote you might consider fitting a linear regression to $\log(1-Y)$. This doesn't seem to apply to your data since it appears to reach "1" (at least to the given accuracy, but since we only have 2 significant figures here, greater data accuracy might avoid the 'exact' '1' values).

There are many other possibilities.

Comment: Can you share your work on a linear regression to `log(1−Y)` on my dataset.

Comment: 1. Note that the model is terrible. It doesn't fit these data (using either of the methods I mentioned). 2. You seem to be asking me to run regressions for you which sounds like I'd be doing your classwork for you. Where do your difficulties lay with running such a regression? Beyond deciding for yourself what to do about the points where Y=1, it's routine work in any package, and numerous questions discuss fitting linear regression models, with examples.

Comment: I got `log(Y-1)=-0.1058X-0.5994` or `Y=1-e^(-0.1058X-0.5994)` which doesn't seem to be good at all. Can you please explain in a more simpler way.

Comment: @Ali That's not the model you asked for. What do you get when you take logs of the complement of the right hand side?  [However the model you just fitted there will fit the data better]

Comment: I get this: log(1-Y):[-0.721246399, 
-0.853871964,
-1,
-1.15490196,
-1.397940009,
-1.698970004,
-2,
-2,
#NUM!,
#NUM!,
#NUM!]

Comment: I should also add that the function approaches the asymptote but variability in the data is so insignificant in my experiment. That's why I consider constant `1` after some point.

Comment: 1. The answer to my previous question should be algebraic not numeric. I don't even know what you're doing there. 2. If the variability is really tiny why only give data to 2 figures?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40479/discussion-between-ali-abbasinasab-and-glen-b).